# Firebase cloud function http sending push notification to device successfully but it falls into the catch block with empty error

Tags: node.js, firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud function HTTP send a push notification to device,
notification is sending successfully but it falls into the catch
block with an empty error instead of response block

here's my index.js code:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var missingData = [];

    var tokenPass = request.query.token_passed ? request.query.token_passed : missingData.push({
        key : 'token',
        message : "Token cannot be null"
    });

    if (missingData.length > 0) {
        response.status(403);
        responseData = {
            status : 403,
            success : false,
            message : "Missing data input",
            data : missingData
        }
        response.send(responseData);
        return;
    }

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Hi',
            body: 'Body'
        }
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenPass, payload)
    .then((response) => {
        response.status(200);
        response.send({
            status : 200,
            success : true,
            message : "send notification successful"
        });
        return;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        response.status(500);
        response.send({
            status : 500,
            success : false,
            err: error,
            message : "internal error"
        });
        return;
    });
});
```

Here's the response which I get:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "success": false,
    "err": {},
    "message": "internal error"
}
```

I tried doing like this too, but no success:

```
var message = {
    notification: {
        title: titlePass,
        body: bodyPass
    },
    token: tokenPass
};

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.
admin.messaging().send(message)
```

P.S. I added the stripe module to my firebase functions, could it be causing issues?

Comment: Is push notifications receiving to your device?

Comment: @krbalaji yes, in both cases.

Comment: Yes. I thought you are using same `response` key in sending admin.messaging(). change this one. outer level response key also same one

Comment: Note sure if this is causing the problem (not having an error is making it hard to be certain), but your code is setting the `status` of the response twice. More idiomatic: `response.status(200).send("send notification successful");`

Comment: Thank you :) actually, more than one response was conflicting. Fixed it with changing the inner response to "res".